# input file attribute this.files[0].name is not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

This code is working fine in FF & Chrome. But IE this is not working.
Is there a way around this?

```
var fileField = document.getElementById('fileField'); 

fileField.onchange = function() {
  fileField.setAttribute("data-original-title", this.files[0].name);
}
```

Comment: Which version of ie ?

Comment: This won't work on IE<10.

Comment: Need to get this working on IE8 and above

Comment: Apparently IE does not support `files[0]`, but the [W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) offers an alternative syntax that you might like to try: `this.files.item(0).name`.  I should add, I don't have access to any IE machines to test this.

Comment: Thanks mate. Tried. But its not working

Answer (score -1):

Try `this.files.first().name` instead of `this.files[0].name`

Comment: Maybe `$(this).files.first().name` ?

Comment: No luck either with this mate.